# OpenEJB Local Client Injection Fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, integration-testing, openejb

Note that I'm mirroring the [example given here](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/openejb/branches/openejb-3.1.x/examples/testcase-injection?r=942990&r=942990&r=1040203&r=942990&r=942990&r=942990&r=942990&r=942990&r=942990&r=1040203&r=942990&r=942990&r=942990&r=1040203&r=1040203&r=942990&r=942990&r=942990&r=942990) very closely.

In fact, my situation is somewhat simpler as I'm not even testing with a persistence unit at this point. My test project provides a simple MDB and a session bean; both the MDB and the session bean are getting loaded as normal, and can be successfully tested (in a constrained fashion) without injection.

The suggested injection with the `@LocalClient` annotation on my unit tests is failing with the known error:

`javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to find injection meta-data for [your-class].  Ensure that class was annotated with @org.apache.openejb.api.LocalClient and was successfully discovered and deployed.  See http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/local-client-injection.html`

When I visit this page it informs me that I may need to add an extra property to my test case context setup. So that now looks like:

> ```
> @Override
> public void setUp() throws Exception {
>     initializeContext();
> }
> ```

```
public void initializeContext() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
    // the property i've added
    p.put("openejb.tempclassloader.skip", "annotations");

    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(p);
        initialContext.bind("inject", this);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) { 
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
    }
}
```

But it's still failing. I really like this idiom and would be very excited if I could successfully use it in my projects.

A few other notes:

- I am providing an 'empty' ejb-jar.xml (in src/main/resources) and an application-client.xml (in src/test/resources) as suggested by Apache to tell OpenEJB to scan the classpath [UPDATE: as it turns out, I was doing this wrong. See my answer below for the suggestion that worked for me.]
- The test cases annotated with `@LocalClient` aren't identified by the OpenEJB engine as actually getting picked up and processed properly (as my MDBs are, for example)

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is likely caused by improper location of the descriptors which hint OpenEJB which sorts of modules are available.

To ensure the test-classes get picked up properly, make sure you're placing a file named `application-client.xml` at `src/test/resources/META-INF` with the following content:

> `<application-client/>`

This should force OpenEJB to scan and react to the presence of `@LocalClient` annotations.

Comment: Glad you found the issue and double thanks for posting the answer.  I've filed a JIRA for an improvement where we could add this to the list of things we could check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-1570

Comment: Side note is that @LocalClient is no longer required in OpenEJB 4, neither are any deployment descriptors.  Not yet released, but it's looking really good.  We need to get a little further on the CDI support then kick out a beta.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to test stuff in a test project called [tomee-embedded-trial](https://github.com/amanica/tomee-embedded-trial.git) and it turned out that openejb ignores stuff called tomee-.*  .

I fixed it for me by specifying the following system properties:
`openejb.deployments.classpath.include=".*-trial.*"`        `openejb.deployments.package.include=".*-trial.*"`