# How to build a auto reply JMS listener in JUnit (in OpenEJB)

Tags: java, junit, jms, openejb, message-driven-bean

I have a EJB to send a message to JMS queue and wait the reply from it. I want to test the EJB, it's easy to use OpenEJB to do the JUnit test of the EJB. But the problem is this EJB will wait the JMS response to continue process.

Although I can send message in my junit code, but because the EJB is still on-going, I cannot run it before the EJB is completed.

2nd solution is I can initialize a MDB to listen and reply the JMS message form the EJB, but the problem is the MDB must in src\main\java and cannot in src\test\java. The problem is this is just a test code and I should not package it to production environment. (I use Maven)

Or should I use mock object ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track.  There area few ways to handle this. Here are a couple tips for unit testing with OpenEJB and Maven.

## Test beans

You can write all sorts of EJBs and other testing utilities and have them deployed.  All you need is a `ejb-jar.xml` for the test code like so:

- `src/main/resources/ejb-jar.xml`   *(the normal one)*
- `src/test/resources/ejb-jar.xml`   *(the testing beans)*

As usual the `ejb-jar.xml` file only needs to contain `<ejb-jar/>` and nothing more.  Its existence simply tells OpenEJB to inspect that part of the classpath and scan it for beans.  Scanning the entire classpath is very slow, so this is just convention to speed that up.

## TestCase injection

With the above `src/test/resources/ejb-jar.xml` you could very easily add that test-only MDB and have it setup to process the request in a way that the TestCase needs.  But the `src/test/resources/ejb-jar.xml` also opens up some other interesting functionality.

You could have the `TestCase` itself do it by declaring references to whatever JMS resources you need and have them injected.

```
import org.apache.openejb.api.LocalClient;

@LocalClient
public class ChatBeanTest extends TestCase {

    @Resource
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(name = "QuestionBean")
    private Queue questionQueue;

    @Resource(name = "AnswerQueue")
    private Queue answerQueue;

    @EJB
    private MyBean myBean;


    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(p);

        initialContext.bind("inject", this); // here's the magic!
    }
}
```

Now you're just one thread away from being able to respond to the JMS message the testcase itself.  You can launch off a little runnable that will read a single message, send the response you want, then exit.

Maybe something like:

```
public void test() throws Exception {

    final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

                connection.start();

                final Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                final MessageConsumer incoming = session.createConsumer(requestQueue);
                final String text = ((TextMessage) incoming.receive(1000)).getText();

                final MessageProducer outgoing = session.createProducer(responseQueue);
                outgoing.send(session.createTextMessage("Hello World!"));

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();

    myBean.doThatThing();

    // asserts here...
}
```

See

## Alternate Descriptors

If you did want to use the MDB solution and only wanted to enable it for just the one test and not all tests, you could define it in a special `src/test/resources/mockmdb.ejb-jar.xml` file and enable it in the specific test case(s) where it is needed.

See [this doc](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/alternate-descriptors.html) for more information on how to enable that descriptor and the various options of alternate descriptors.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. I'm not sure which one is better, originally I think another MDB is better, but it seems thread is also good in this case. Btw, I don't the Alternate Descriptors before, it's really cool, I need this features in other situation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use mocks for this.  If you're sending messages to a real JMS server, listening for them, replying to them, etc. then you're doing something other than a unit test. I'm not going to get into the argument about what that should be called, but I think it's pretty well universally accepted that a unit-test shouldn't be talking to live databases, message queues, etc.

Comment: I know it's not a good practice to do unit test with an external JMS server. That's why I use OpenEJB, it's a embedded container. I just use it to test a message driven bean and it's good.

Comment: Even using an embedded container, I'll argue that it's not a "unit test" if you're using a live message queue.  Granted, this may be a controversial point, but I've always considered the point of a unit test to be to keep the dependencies to a minimum and to test only the logic of the unit being tested...  If you use a live message queue, or an in memory database, or whatever, you risk that you're testing the embedded container or the in memory database, not your code.

Of course mocks also open up the possibility that you're testing the mock object framework, but that's less risk, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correct - It's a bad design to have an EJB send a JMS message and then await a response, in fact contradictory to the whole idea of EJB.

You send a JMS message, and then forget about it. You have an MDB to receive the message. If the EJB depends on a response, JMS is not the way to go, but rather use another EJB.

To test the sending, mock the JMS classes, test the MDB separately.

EJB's are designed for synchronous tasks, JMS for asynchronous tasks - if you have to do asynchronous communication to an external system, I suggest you design your system after that, and do proper asynchronous flows. An EJB that sits and waits for a JMS reply is at best an ugly hack, and will not add any good to your system design.

Comment: In my case, MDB is just for test purpose, I don't want to use it if possible. The requirement is AP should send message and wait the reply, is there any other design idea for it? Because EJB can use dependency injection to access JMS queue, therefore I use EJB to send JMS. Please let me know if there is other good design, thanks.

Comment: Yes by all means send JMS from the EJB, but that same EJB must not wait for a reply. If you need to take action on a reply, the EJB should persist any state that you need to track, then send the JMS message, and return from method. Then have another MDB receive the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for David's answer, it's what I want. I know unit test should not depend on other external resource like JMS server. But if I use Maven + OpenEJB, I still can let the test code in a closed environment. It can help to do automatically test with external resource dependency, especially for some old programs which not easy to refactor.

And if you see the following error message in initialContext.bind("inject", this)

Ensure that class was annotated with @org.apache.openejb.api.LocalClient and was successfully discovered and deployed.

One reference is http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/local-client-injection.html, but add "openejb.tempclassloader.skip=annotations" doesn't work for me. Please check this doc [OpenEJB Local Client Injection Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254947/openejb-local-client-injection-fails). There is already a patch for it, I think it will be fixed in OpenEJB 3.1.5 or 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Also I've found it is best practice to actually break out your logic in your MDB to a different class. This isolates your business logic from being in an MDB and allows you to expose your logic as more than one way (MDB, EJB, Web Service, POJO, etc.). It also allows you to more easily test your business logic without the need to test the protocol (JMS in this case).

As for testing JMS, mocking may be the better choice. Or if you really need to test the protocol "in container" look at using something like the JBoss Microcontainer (I believe you can get this packaged with some of the JBoss projects like Seam). Then you can fire up a mini-container for testing things like EJB and JMS.

But overall, it is best to avoid having to need a container unless absolutely necessary. That's why separating your business logic from your implementation logic (even if you don't use mocks) is a good practice.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I doesn't illustrate my situation clear. MDB is not necessary in my case. There is a legacy system and it provides a JMS interface. Our application send JMS to this legacy and wait it's response. <br/>

The problem is when JUnit is running the test case to send JMS message and wait reply, I need a solution to get the message and reply it. 1st idea is I can use test code (a POJO) to reply the JMS, and the 2dn idea is to use MDB to do the response.

Comment: Maybe mock is better solution, but I just have another idea. If I use multithread in my junit code, the 1st thread calls the EJB and wait. The 2nd thread to listen the queue and reply it.

But it seems JUnit doesn't support multithread (seems needs extension) or use TestNG, it seems support multithread test.